# AWS S3 Bucket Policy - public and principal specific permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

How do i specify a policy that accomplishes

- public allow permission on s3:getObject
- specific principal allow permission on s3:*

My use case is I want to provide public read access to bucket resources (as long as requestor knows exact key) but want to provide full admin access for a specific iam role.

I tried this

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1527265803757",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1527265797507",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::99999999999:role/my-role"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1527700198181",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
        },        
    ]
}
```

but the it seems to reduce the role to only having `getObject` permission.

Comment: it seems, it is correct

Answer (score 0):

I tried your policy and for the my-role, I was able to run putobject....while for others I could only run getobject. What makes you believe that my-role does not have admin access?

Comment: in my tests, this policy failed when the role attempted to do putobject/putobjecttagging. when i removed the `everyone` principal it worked. Is there another reason why this might be the case?

Comment: Interesting... I used the IAM Policys simulator to test putobject function. Did you try the CLI from your desktop or another ec2 instance? Maybe the ec2 instance may not have sufficient roles/privileges.

Comment: this is from desktop.